# JSON - Need to be javascript array inside of array and encode to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to produce an array that looks like this:

```
[
      {
        "values": [ 
          [1, 0], 
          [2, -6.3382185140371], 
          [3, -5.9507873460847], 
          [4, -11.569146943813], 
          [5, -5.4767332317425], 
          [6, 0.50794682203014], 
          [7, -5.5310285460542], 
          [8, -5.7838296963382], 
          [9, -7.3249341615649], 
          [10, -6.7078630712489] 
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I'm doing an array in javascript that looks like this and only produce the values, but doe not place it within `"values" : []`:

```
var myArray = new Array(10);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      myArray[i] = new Array(2);
      myArray[i][0] = i;
      myArray[i][1] = 5;
    }    

    var jsonEncoded = JSON.stringify(myArray);
    return jsonEncoded;
```

I'm sure this is an easy answer, but I'm not experience enough to know. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Do the values within the arrays matter (i.e., the `-6.33…` part of `[2, -6.33…]`)?

Comment: At this moment they do not, we are simply getting it to work and then will control the values later with equations.

Comment: really not clear what the question is

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, you basically need to wrap your `myArray` in an object and put that object into another array.

```
var myArray = new Array(10);
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  myArray[i] = new Array(2);
  myArray[i][0] = i;
  myArray[i][1] = 5;
}
var result = [{values: myArray}];

var jsonEncoded = JSON.stringify(result);
return jsonEncoded;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var jsonEncoded = JSON.stringify([{values:myArray}]);
```

There are several other, more verbose ways to do it, but that's it.

In this case, myArray is an array containing N elements, each one being an array of two numbers.

Enclosing {key : value} pairs in curly bracers { } means you're declaring an object. In this case, "values" is your key, and myArray is your value. No pun intended here, it's just that you picked a confusing keyname. Object notation in js does not require quoting the key.

Finally, enclosing the aforementioned object  between brackets will result in an array whose only element is that object.